# Can “as" be used to introduce a longer background action or situation?

Tags: word-usage, clauses

> 1. **As** they were sleeping, somebody broke into the house.
> 2. **As** I was driving down the street, I saw Peter.
> 3. **As** I walked through the park I remembered about my mother's birthday.

Do these sentences sound natural? Can I use “as“ in this way?

I know that “when“ or “while" can be used to introduce a longer background action or situation. I am just wondering whether I could use “as" in this way.

Answer (score 1):

The sentences are OK.

*as* used here is not an introduction but as a conjunction for events happening at the same time.
See Collins [as](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/as) sense 6:

> 6) at the same time that; while   ⇒ "she laughed as she spoke"